# Unable to set button action specific to object in row for TableViewCell

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, uibutton

I have a TableViewCell class set for a tableView. I dropped a button in the cell and connected it to the TableViewCell.h I want the action of the button, when pressed, to do something specific to the object displayed in the row. For example, when pressed it should save object property "name" which is not displayed in any labels.

In my TableViewCell.h I set the button action and delegate:

```
- (IBAction)pressBtn:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate tableViewCell:self];
}
```

In my TableViewController.m I include a delegate:

```
-(void)tableViewCell:(tableViewCell *)cell {
//...some code...//
            NSIndexPath *indexPath;
            Car *car = self.cars[indexPath.row];
            [newCar setValue:car.name forKey:@"name"];
```

The problem is I return whatever is at the first cell, even though I click on the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th. self.cars is an array.
How can I point to the object (and its properties) for the selected cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tableViewController , use code like this `[tableView indexPathForCell:cell]` to get the indexPath , the row is you wanted.

Comment: I've added: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:cell]; but it keeps looking at the first cell.

Comment: Thanks, i have a bunch of if statements with and missed updated one section with the code. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Set a `button tag` for every button that you create for a `UITableViewCell`.

What I would do is set `UIButton` tag to `indexpath.row` value.

Answer (score 0):

Give the button a tag like Sreejith mentioned. Once you have the tag in place, you can get the cell by the tag

```
- (IBAction)pressBtn:(id)sender {
int btnTag=[sender tag];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:btnTag];
//and perform operations on that cell.
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error for 'int' line of code: expected identifier. and i've added: UIButton *pressBtn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];. Did i miss something?

Comment: I'm also getting 'implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSindexPath'disallowed with arc.

Answer (score 0):

If the selection of `Car` instance is not fully dependent on the view controller, try this,

in `TableviewCell.h` add a @property for Car

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Car *car;
```

and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method in viewController

```
Car *car = self.cars[indexPath.row];
cell.car = car;
```

so the car instance for the current cell will be in that custom cell class. So that you can do whatever operations with that object. ie.

```
- (IBAction)pressBtn:(id)sender {

     //you can directly call self.car to get current car instance
     //and do the stuff here itself
}
```